# Style not loading properly in firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I recently developed a quick and dirty website for my band. Everything is working perfectly in chrome & safari but when i load the page in firefox it looks like the stylesheet isn't loading at all and everything is just being shown as if it has no style rules. Here is the link: http://www.neverwakemusic.com/

I would greatly appreciate any help on this as we are expecting heavy traffic on the site within the next few days due to our new album release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few errors in your CSS file

- You have two invalid rules which contain `input[type="text]`. You are missing the closing `"`. It should be `input[type="text"]`
- the `@charset` rule must be the first thing in the file.
- `font-color` should be `color`

etc..

In general you should validate your CSS to find such issues at the http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator

For example your style.css ([*validation of file*](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http://www.neverwakemusic.com/css/style.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en))
(*ignore vendor specific rules and look for genuine errors in syntax etc..*)

Comment: Thanks. That closing quote fixed it. Seems like webkit browsers are pretty forgiving compared to firefox.

Comment: @mrg1023 The WebKit browsers generally don't implement the error-recovery portions of the CSS spec correctly (unlike Firefox, Opera, and IE).  This can lead to all sorts of rendering differences on invalid CSS, in spite of the CSS working groups attempts to make that impossibl by specifying the error-recovery behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Line 391 in your stylesheet, broken quote is causing Firefox's parser to stop:

```
#contactForm input[type="text]:focus {
```